# How to set timeout as false in find query to get rid of "cursor id not found Execution halted" issue in Mongolite(R)

Tags: r, mongolite

I am getting "cursor id  not found Execution halted" issue in Mongolite(R). But I dont know how to set timeout flag as false in find query uisng mongolite package in R.

Answer (score 0):

I think the interface doesn't make everything public, but I've developed an ugly hack, as the internal function mongo_collection_find does have an argument no_timeout:

```
mlite <- mongo()
iterate2 <- function (query = "{}", fields = "{\"_id\":0}", sort = "{}",skip = 0, limit = 0, no_timeout=FALSE) {
  check_col()
  cur <- mongo_collection_find(col, query = query, sort = sort, fields = fields, skip = skip, limit = limit, no_timeout=no_timeout)
  mongo_iterator(cur)
}
environment(iterate2) <- environment(mlite$iterate)
results <- iterate2(no_timeout=TRUE)$page()
```

Besides setting no_timeout, the code is the same as mlite$iterate

It works, even though it is ugly (iterate2 is stand-alone, no longer a method of mlite).

And be careful that AFAIK there is no garbage control for your cursor, so unless you are really careful your cursor is always exhausted, you just introduced a memory leak. I guess you'd have to restart mongo to truly get rid of your cursor.